# Find magnetic field in a solenoid for different regions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

Problem statement:

> A steady current I flows along an infinitely long hollow cylindrical conductor of radius $R$. This cylinder is placed coaxially inside an infinite solenoid of radius $2R$. The solenoid has $n$ turns per unit length and carries a steady current $I$. Consider a point $\text{P}$ at a distance $r$ from the common axis.
>
> The correct statement(s) is (are):
>
> - (A) In the region $0 < r < R$, the magnetic field is non-zero
> - (B) In the region $R < r < 2R$, the magnetic field is along the common axis.
> - (C) In the region $R < r < 2R$, the magnetic field is tangential to the circle of radius r, centered on the axis.
> - (D) In the region $r > 2R$, the magnetic field is non-zero.

The given solution is that both (A) and (D) are correct statements.  However, is there an alternate argument for (C) is also being correct since the magnetic field in the region $R < r < 2R$ is touches the circle of radius $r$ only at a single point and meets all the requirements of being a tangent?

A detailed argument can be found here:

[image: Analysis of Option C]

Comment: There is obviously only one solenoid, and no question asked...

Comment: Yeah I corrected it. It would be great if you could answer it too.

Comment: Sorry, what is the question exactly ?

Comment: The question tells us about a situation and we have to tell them which if the given options are correct. Since the answer given is AD , I have a doubt whether the answer can be C too.

Comment: well, in your reasoning, every vector is tangent to any circle...

Comment: Not every vector. Only the vectors in the tangential plane to the circle.

Comment: In my understanding of the question, a vector tangent to a circle is included in the circle's plane.

Comment: Well but as far as tangent are defined , they are curves that touch a circle at only one point. So by that definition it seems these vectors too are tangents.

Comment: Again,  in your reasoning, every vector is tangent to any circle...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about the definition of a tangent than about physics.

Answer (score 1):

Tangent to any curve is defined as a line touching the curve at a single point and that lies in the plane of the curve. Hence only [A] vector is the tangential vector. A tangential vector indicates the slope and hence it must lie on the plane of the curve

Answer (score 0):

tangent is a secant where point A tends to point B 
please refer to the definition of tangent https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#Tangent_line_to_a_curve

hence answer ad looks correct